# How to use Regex to identify specific line? c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, text

I'm new to regex and still don't understand it well

I need to identify a line but for some reason I always gets false when using regex

line to identify structure: **Screen Message: FULL PATH \ FILENAME.PNG**

example:

```
Screen Message: c:\program files (x86)\regression machine work\reports\156487/04-37-71_47-38-141\Screenmessages\63445646476476767574.FAR.png
```

tried to go for the prefix ("Screen Message: ") and the suffix (".FAR.png")
but couldn't get it to work

```
Regex.Match(Text, $"(^Screen Message: )+[0-9]+[a-z]\+{.FAR.png}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
```

Any help would be appreciated
thanks

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you need to check. Your explanation and code are not clear enough and I have a couple of questions, for example, why do you escape `+` in your regex?

Comment: How about this? `(^Screen Message: )+(.+)\/([^\/]+)(\w+\.FAR\.png)`

Comment: do you want only the success of the match? don't need any of the sub strings?. Do you have some examples of a negative match? line that are similar to this one but should not be matched?

Comment: If my answer does not help you solve the issue, please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like

```cs
Screen Message:\s*(?<folder>.*)\\(?<filename>.*\.FAR\.png)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b6c4zR/2). *Details*:

- `Screen Message:` - a string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `(?<folder>.*)` - Group "folder": any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `(?<filename>.*\.FAR\.png)` - Group "filename": any zero or more chars as many as possible, and then a `.FAR.png` substring

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/z1vzWT):

```cs
var pattern = @"Screen Message:\s*(?<folder>.*)\\(?<filename>.*\.FAR\.png)";
var input = @"Screen Message: c:\program files (x86)\regression machine work\reports\156487/04-37-71_47-38-141\Screenmessages\63445646476476767574.FAR.png";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Folder: '{0}', filename: '{1}'", 
        match.Groups["folder"].Value, match.Groups["filename"].Value);
}
```